# How to read csv files in Python with incremental names and create different objects?

Tags: python, csv, readfile

I have lots of files name like "XXXXX_1.csv", "XXXX_2.csv","XXXX_3.csv"...."XXXX_n.csv"
I would like to read them and create df1, df2, df3...... How should I do this? In R, I could write like

```
fname <- filename[i]
assign(paste0("dry_shell",i),fread(paste0("/mnt/Wendy/Data/",fname)))
}
```

But how about Python? I would like to have different dataframes like df1,df2,df3 that assign to dataframe1, dataframe2, etc.

Comment: Generally, one does not dynamically create variables in Python. It is overall a poor programming practice. You should instead *use a container*, in this case, a `dict` might be a natural choice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are all named nicely you can iterate over a range of numbers to get all the files:

```py
# this will open and do something to all files named csv_0, csv_1, and csv_2 in the
# directory /path/to/files
for i in range(3):
    with open(f"/path/to/files/csv_{i}") as file:
        # do something with the csv file ...
```

You could also provide a path to a directory and achieve the same goal by opening and processing all the files in the dictionary:

```py
import os

for path in os.listdir():
    with open(path) as file:
        # do something with the csv file ...
```

See here for the documentation for the python (v3.8.5) standard [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume you are using `datatable` (I noticed the `fread` function). The equivalent, dataframe wise, in python is Pandas. You can combine [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) with Pandas to create a dictionary of dataframes :

```
from pathlib import Path
directory = Path(directory that contains  "XXXXX_1.csv", "XXXX_2.csv","XXXX_3.csv"...."XXXX_n.csv")
{f"df{n}": pd.read_csv(file) for n, file in enumerate(directory.iterdir(),1)}
```